# How split an element and replace both part in list with python

Tags: python, list, indexing, replace

I've a list like:

```
mylist = ['La', 'domestication', "d'un", 'animal', 'ou', "d'un", 'végétal,', 'necessite', "l'acquisition", "d'une", 'ferme']
```

I want to split elements which have " **'** " inside by 2 elements and keep their index in the original list.

```
OUTPUT REQUESTED : my_new_list = ['La', 'domestication', "d'" ,'un', 'animal', 'ou', "d'", 'un', 'végétal,', 'necessite', "l'", 'acquisition', "d'", 'une', 'ferme']
```

I've tried few thing but I admit I'm stuck to replace the two new split element in the correct index, here is the code I've tried:

```
for word in mylist:
    if "'" in word:
        new_words = word.split("'")
        mylist[mylist.index(word)] = (new_words[0]+"'")
        mylist.insert(mylist.index((new_words[0]+"'")+1), new_words[1]) 

print(mylist)
```

Thank you for your time and help :)

Comment: This would be much easier if you actually made a new list for your result, instead of modifying the original list.

Comment: What if a word has 2 or more quotes?

Comment: @ScottHunter : Sure, but I need to keep index position and replace the old  word by the 2 new sliced

Comment: And yet you accepted @Nick's answer, which does exactly that.

Comment: @ScottHunter: In fairness, any solution that makes a new `list` can be trivially tweaked to alter the original `list` (for when you're relying on aliases of the `list` seeing the modification), so it hardly matters which solution is used (aside from the minor memory expense of having two at once). Just change `my_new_list = operation_on(mylist)` to `mylist[:] = operation_on(mylist)` and it swaps out the contents in-place (then discards the temporary).

Comment: @ShadowRanger: My point (not clearly made, obviously) was that accepting a solution that did not modify the original argued against the requirement of doing so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you're happy with creating a new list, one way to achieve that is to join the existing list together with spaces and then split on either a space or a `'`:

```py
import re

mylist = [
 'La', 'domestication', "d'un",
 'animal', 'ou', "d'un", 'végétal,',
 'necessite', "l'acquisition",
 "d'une", 'ferme'
]

my_new_list = re.split(r" |(?<=')", ' '.join(mylist))
```

Output:

```
[
 'La', 'domestication', "d'", 'un',
 'animal', 'ou', "d'", 'un', 'végétal,',
 'necessite', "l'", 'acquisition',
 "d'", 'une', 'ferme'
]
```

Note this assumes the words in the list don't have a space in them; if they might, you can just replace the space in the code with a character (or character sequence) which does not occur in the words, e.g. `\0`:

```
my_new_list = re.split(r"\0|(?<=')", '\0'.join(mylist))
```

Comment: Assumes (reasonably) that entries in the original list don't have any spaces in them.

Comment: @ScottHunter agreed, what is in the list is whole words; but it would be easy enough to replace space with a character such as `#`

Comment: @ScottHunter I've added a note to the answer about that possibilty

Comment: @Nick: Or more safely, some character sequence that's *guaranteed* not to appear in the input. If the input is text, `'\0'` would be a good choice, or you can just make some long enough string of garbage that's statistically unlikely to occur (assuming you're not worrying about malicious input), e.g. `'\0\f\v\a'` or the like.

Comment: @ShadowRanger yeah, I was trying not to over-complicate...

Comment: @Nick: Sure. I don't expect you to add it to the answer, but it's useful for people who need a more resilient solution.

Comment: @ShadowRanger `'\0'` *is* better than `'#'`. I've updated...

Comment: @Thurro No worries - I'm glad it was helpful

Comment: Thank you all again! I will study the Re library to continue to improve my code.

Answer (score 4):

```
mylist = ['La', 'domestication', "d'un", 'animal', 'ou', "d'un", 'végétal,', 'necessite', "l'acquisition", "d'une", 'ferme']
newlist = []

for word in mylist:
    ele = word.split("'")
    if len(ele) > 1:
        for i in range (0,len(ele)):
            if i == 0:
                newlist.append(ele[i]+"'")
            else:
                newlist.append(ele[i])
    else:
        newlist.append(ele[0])

print (mylist)
print (newlist)
```

Answer (score 4):

A (slightly) simpler variation on previous answers, that makes no assumptions about the strings in your list:

```
newlist = []

for word in mylist:
    bits = word.split("'")
    for w in bits[:-1]:
        newlist.append(w+"'")
    newlist.append(bits[-1])
```

Comment: Simple is always good

Answer (score 3):

```
mylist = ['La', 'domestication', "d'un", 'animal', 'ou', "d'un", 'végétal,', 'necessite', "l'acquisition", "d'une", 'ferme']
new_list = []
for word in mylist:
    if "'" in word:
        parts = word.split("'")
        for i in range(len(parts)-1):
            new_lst.append(parts[i]+"'")
        new_list.append(parts[-1])
    else:
        new_list.append(word)
```

Answer (score 2):

I just modified your code.

```
   mylist = ['La', 'domestication', "d'un", 'animal', 'ou', "d'un", 'végétal,', 'necessite', "l'acquisition", "d'une", 'ferme']

lol = str("")
print(lol)
for word in mylist:
    
    if "'" in word:
        new_words = word.split("'")
        for i in new_words:
            lol=lol+"0"+str(i).encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')
    else:
        lol=lol+"0"+str(word).encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')
        
if lol[0]=="0":
    lol = lol[1:]
    
lol = lol.split("0")
print(lol)
```

Comment: What if `0` appears in any of the words?

Comment: As @ShadowRanger suggested use some character sequence that's guaranteed not to appear in the input.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `enumerate()` to get the index you are iterating at, then use array slicing to replace at the correct position.

```py
mylist = ['La', 'domestication', "d'un", 'animal', 'ou', "d'un", 'végétal,', 'necessite', "l'acquisition", "d'une", 'ferme']

for i, w in enumerate(mylist):
    if "'" in w:
        mylist[i:i+1] = w.split("'")
```

Now printing my `mylist` gives us:

`['La', 'domestication', 'd', 'un', 'animal', 'ou', 'd', 'un', 'végétal,', 'necessite', 'l', 'acquisition', 'd', 'une', 'ferme']`

Edit: This is bad code. Don't do this.

Comment: Desired result should include the quotes.

Comment: I'm kinda amused this works. It's doing something unsafe (modifying a `list` as you iterate over it), but the end result is fine, it just does a little unnecessary work checking the results of a split (because the loop picks up on the new element(s) following the replaced element).

Comment: @ScottHunter: Assuming only one separator per string, `str.partition` could be used for the purpose, but otherwise, you're stuck with regex to do that. Boo.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I know! Everything about screams WRONG! to me! :)

Comment: @ShadowRanger Actually now that I looked at it, I am surprised it works too :)

Comment: @aelmosalamy: I had to run the code, then trace the behavior in my head to believe it was really safe. But it is. You just end up replacing `'d'un'` with `'d', 'un'`, then the next loop (which, under the hood is just indexing with a one-up counter without rechecking the length) seamlessly, and unnecessarily, rechecks `'un'`. Inserting in reverse would have issues (just like removing in forward order has issues), but this happens to be a perfectly safe, if mildly wasteful, thing to do. Still chuckling a bit at it. :-)

Comment: @ShadowRanger Haha, code like this is why people find C difficult, Thank you Python. Its also interesting how `enumerate` handles the changes in the actual array.

Comment: @aelmosalamy: It's not `enumerate` doing it, it's the `list`'s iterator. `enumerate` happily keeps going as long as the underlying iterator it wraps keeps producing values. `list`'s iterator enables this by (unlike `dict`'s iterator) not checking for (a subset of) unsafe modifications, and rechecking the length of the underlying `list` as it goes, rather than caching it up front. I doubt the language guarantees this behavior of `list` iterators, so you definitely shouldn't rely on it (non-CPython interpreters might fail, and future CPython might change the behavior).